# Laravel - multiple selection and saving to database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have this small project for car posts. I make my post so everything is working properly, but now i need to have multiple selections. So this is my `PostsController`:

```
...
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'brand' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required',
            'cc' => 'required',
            'hp' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'fuel' => 'required',
            'safety' => 'required'
        ]);


        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->brand = $request->input('brand');
        $post->model = $request->input('model');
        $post->age = $request->input('age');
        $post->cc = $request->input('cc');
        $post->hp = $request->input('hp');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->fuel = $request->input('fuel');
        $post->safety = $request->input('safety');
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Your post is posted!');
    }
...
```

And now this is my `createpost.blade.php` :

```
...
<div class="column">
<label for="safety">Safety:</label></br>
 <select class="form-control" name="safety">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <option value="diesel">ABS</option>
   <option value="gasoline">ESP</option>
   <option value="electric">CHILD LOCK</option>
   <option value="electric">AirBAG</option>
 </select>
</div>
...
```

How can i make this select input for multiple selection and all of the selections need to save into my database? I have my `Post.php` model:

```
...
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Please help if anybody have solutions for this? Or some tutorials or any help similar!

Comment: you may try `checkbox` input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array in your blade.php file and also use multiple

```
<select class="form-control" name="safety[]" multiple>
```

In controller

```
$post->safety = implode(',', $request->input('safety'));
```

Comment: Okay this works! I don't know why do you have -1 on this answer because this is working! It's saving to database whatever I select. Only know I need to find another way of selecting, currently it's with control/cmd...

Answer (score 1):

Try some multi select libraries

[Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) is one among them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `checkbox` in `blade` file

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target.checked ? e.target.value : e.target.value+' is unchecked')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="safety">Safety:</label></br>

   <input type="checkbox" value="ABS" name="safety[]" />ABS
   <input type="checkbox" value="ESP" name="safety[]" />ESP
   <input type="checkbox" value="CHILD LOCK" name="safety[]" />CHILD LOCK
   <input type="checkbox" value="AirBAG" name="safety[]" />AirBAG
</div>
```

And retrieve your data from `$request` in **controller** as follows:

```
$request->input('safety') // return an array with all checked value, e.g: ['ABS','ESP']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nice solution for select option!

Answer (score 0):

add **multiple** attribute in select tag

change

```
<select class="form-control" name="safety[]">
```

to

```
<select class="form-control" name="safety[]" multiple>
```

This will let you select multiple options.
User will have to use control/cmd key to select multiple options

Comment: With this solution it shows me a problem ```Array to string conversion```

Comment: you are wriong because name should be in array like `<select class="form-control" name="safety[]">`